# How to make the y-axis in Excel into categorical namen

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to make a plot with categorical data (y-axis) with correspondenting continue data (x-axis).

But the axis seem to keep switching it around e.g. the continues data stays on the y-axis and the categorical data on the y-axis. Switching the rows and columns around does not work.

The plot i am trying to recreate with different data

[image]

Comment: The problem is solved. Please remove the sub

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve this.

With an XY scatter chart, create a helper series that has the same Y values as your data and zeros as the X values. Add this as a new series, then add data labels and assign each data label to the cell with the text you want to show. This can be sped up with the free XY Chart Labeler add-in, or in Excel 2013 and higher use "Values from cells" in the data labels settings.

Another way is to create a Horizontal bar chart and stack a series with a uniform small value on top of the original bar series. Use a picture fill for the helper series and format the original series with no fill and no line. This way the stacked picture will float like in the screenshot.

[image]